# Emacs Terminal Mode displays the letter q in front of each command

Tags: terminal, emacs

Whenever I'm using terminal mode, it displays the letter q in front of each command. It doesn't nessercerly change the command, so while I can do everything fine, it's still really annoying. It generally looks like this

```
q[user@ComputerName ~]$
```

with the actual thing looking like this..
[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgnUd.png)

Comment: You say “it displays the letter q in front of each command”, but you show it displaying a ```q``` in front of every *prompt*  — presumably, even if you just hit “Enter” (i.e., enter a null command).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your shell prompt configuration emits the [DECSCUSR](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) sequence to set the cursor shape or blinking (e.g. `\e[1 q` for blinking block, `\e[2 q` for steady block, `\e[5 q` for blinking bar, `\e[6 q` for steady bar). This sequence is not understood by Emacs's terminal, it believes the space character terminates the sequence, hence `q` is treated as a regular letter.

You should adjust your shell's prompt to only emit this sequence for specific terminal emulators (e.g. when `$TERM` begins with `xterm` or another value that's known to support this sequence). If you took your shell prompt configuration from somewhere, you should notify its authors about this problem. You might also want to file a bug report against Emacs.